# Obtaining mouse coordinates in current coordinate system

Tags: processing

How may I obtain the mouse coordinates in the current coordinate system i.e. in the coordinate system determined by the transformation matrix?

mouseX and mouseY return coordinates in untransformed screen space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to keep track of the transformation matrix manually and use the inverse transformation to convert between local and global coordinate systems.

To convert from the global to the local coordinate system, multiply the global position to the inverse of the local coordinate system. Here's a very basic example:

```
//local coordinate system
PMatrix2D coordinateSystem;
//ineverse local coordinate system
PMatrix2D inverseCoordinateSystem;

PVector global = new PVector();
PVector local = new PVector();

void setup(){
  size(400,400);

  coordinateSystem = new PMatrix2D();
  //move to centre
  coordinateSystem.translate(width * .5, height * .5);
  //rotate 45 degrees
  coordinateSystem.rotate(HALF_PI * .5);

  //inverse coordinate system - clone the regular one, then simply invert it
  inverseCoordinateSystem = coordinateSystem.get(); 
  inverseCoordinateSystem.invert();

  fill(128);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);

  pushMatrix();
  applyMatrix(coordinateSystem);
  rect(0,0,100,100);
  popMatrix();

  //set global coordinates
  global.set(mouseX,mouseY);
  //compute local coordinates by multiplying the global coordinates to the inverse local coordinate system (transformation matrix)
  inverseCoordinateSystem.mult(global,local);

  text("global coordinates:" + global+
      "\nlocal coordinates:" + local,15,10);
}
```

Notice that the local coordinates are 0,0 when the cursor is at the top of the diamond.

The same principle applies in 3D, just need to use a [PMatrix3D](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix3D.html) instead

Comment: Thanks. PMatrix2D.invert() and mult() are the key. This question would surely be best answered by perusing the Processing reference... except for the fact that the Processing reference is missing these functions :(

Comment: 'local.set(0,0);' appears redundant.

Comment: @ChrisJJ On top of the Processing reference, you also have the [Processing CoreJavadoc](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/) (linked to from the reference) and even the [source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/core/src/processing/core). I agree, PMatrix isn't included in the reference, most of the time typical Processing users (artists/designers/etc.) will use push/pop matrix calls and screenX()/modelX() to convert back and forth. The idea is to hide the complexity, however, if you do need to go low level with linear algebra/direct GL calls you can

Comment: @ChrisJJ I agree, ```local.set(0,0);``` in this case case is redundant: old habit of having cleared/un-initialised data before any transformation to the data

Comment: "The idea is to hide the complexity" Not a smart idea. If a feature is in the language, it should be in the reference documentation. Anyone who doesn't like a complex feature can himself choose not to read about it.

Comment: If you were experienced with a vector drawing package for example and you had no linear algebra background, what would be less intimidating to you: nested objects with different transformations applied or vector to matrix multiplication ?...[different strokes for different folks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVCtkzIXYzQ).I'm guessing it's helpful to more than one person. Maybe Processing isn't the best language for what you need. Luckily there are so many languages out there with support for graphics, surely one will also tick the marks for your project and be more enjoyable for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this are best answered by perusing [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/). Specifically, the `modelX()` and `modelY()` functions do exactly what you want: they convert from screen coordinates to transformed coordinates.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Did you read the documentation? Have you tried using the P3D renderer? You can still render everything in 2D using the P3D renderer.

Comment: @ChrisJJ The ```P2D``` render supports ```modelX()```,```modelY()```, ```JAVA2D``` and ```FX2D``` do not